# Eclipse Intent Plugin for LibGDX Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, libgdx

How do I create an external link for a LibGDX Project? I want to make an android app but the Android format for putting a link in won't work since I have to put it in the core project.

Answer (score 0):

```
String webUrl = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=com.something.something";
String marketurl = "amzn://apps/android?p=com.something.something";
try{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(marketurl));   
    startActivity(intent);
}catch(Exception e){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(webUrl));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: try using "android.content.Intent" instead of "Intent" in my answer